# Save same date in another variable with different format

Tags: bash, shell, date

I use `DATE_TIME=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%T")` to calculate actual date. I want to format this date in order to get `%d.%m.%Y, %T` and save it as another variable. Unfortunately `DATE_TIME_2=$(date -d $DATE_TIME +"%d.%m.%Y, %T")` does not work. Any tips?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, save the date in a canonical form that you can use as input. A Unix timestamp is a good choice.

```
DATE_TIME=$(date +%s)
```

`DATE_TIME` is now the number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight Jan 1, 1970.

Then use that to compute both of your desired forms.

```
DATE_TIME_1=$(date -d @$DATE_TIME +"%Y-%m-%d_%T")
DATE_TIME_2=$(date -d @$DATE_TIME +"%d.%m.%Y, %T")
```

Note the `@` prefixed to the canonical form; that lets `date` know that the argument to `d` is to be interpreted as a integer timestamp.

Or, just compute a single string with both formats, separated by an unambiguous character:

```
DT=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%T=%d.%m.%Y, %T")
```

Then, you can split that easily with the `read` command.

```
IFS="=" read DATE_TIME DATE_TIME_2 <<< "$DT"
```

Comment: but not on mac OS X, maybe restricted to linux?

Comment: The first part should work in OS X, but requires the call to `date` be modified for the BSD version it uses.  The second should works as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use string manipulations to break your original date into components, then rearrange them:

```
foo=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%T")
parts=(${foo//[-_]/ })
echo "${parts[2]}.${parts[1]}.${parts[0]}, ${parts[3]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

whole lot of syntax, where there's a *much* simpler solution.  e.g *never* fuss with an array.  this will do what you need:

```
data.$ set -- $(date "+%Y %m %d %T")
data.$ echo $*
2015 04 26 19:32:55
data.$ DATE_TIME="$1-$2-$3_$4"
data.$ echo $DATE_TIME
2015-04-26_19:32:55
data.$ DATE_TIME_1="$1.$2.$3, $4"
data.$ echo $DATE_TIME_1
2015.04.26, 19:32:55
data.$
```

there might be some value in learning the syntax, but, ... if you can avoid it, by all means, do.  at this point, with positional parameters, and you need fancier formatting, use "printf" rather than echo.